# Which worksheet contains the value with 3D formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook which has a sheet that finds the lowest price for each item in other worksheets.  The items are all in the same cell in each sheet, and the "composite" sheet has the formula:

`=MIN('sheet1:sheet3'!B3)`

I would like the cell next to it to list the name of the sheet that the value was pulled from.

Answer (score 3):

This is a big, ugly hack and doesn't scale well, but this will work for the way you have it now.

```
=IF(MIN(Sheet1:Sheet3!B3)=Sheet1!B3,"sheet1",IF(MIN(Sheet1:Sheet3!B3)=Sheet2!B3,"sheet2","sheet3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many worksheets, First define the Name:  ***Sheets*** using the Name Manager as :

```
=REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),1,FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)),"")
```

[image]

Pick some cell, say **F1** and enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($A$1:A1)<=COUNTA(Sheets),INDEX(Sheets,ROWS($A$1:A1)),"")
```

and in **G1** enter:

```
=INDIRECT(F1 & "!B3")
```

Copy these down.  This will create of a table of sheets and values.

Finally in **D1** enter:

```
=MIN(G:G)
```

and in **E1** enter:

```
=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(D1,G:G,0))
```

[image]